# Adding Two Columns when a Third Column is Equal

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing a left join query to compare the two tables for any values that do not equal each other on f9 and sumoff6 columns ONLY if the F1 columns are the same. If they are different i would like to subtract them.

The results I am getting show equal values that are already on both tables. I need for f1 columns to match on both tables but if their values on the sumoff6 and f9 columns do not match then display them and subtract them. F1 is unique on both tables. Keeep in mind though that there may be more rows in the statement table. I am using MS Access SQL view.

Query

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9
FROM statement 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1]
WHERE [allocation_final].sumoff6 <> statement.f9
```

Statement table:

```
f1     f9
-----------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.22 
4       86.46
5      170.33
6       96.40
```

allocation_final:

```
f1     SumOff6
--------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.00
4       86.46
5      170.33
6       40.22 
7       22.40
8       70.00
9       96.40
10      50.00
```

Results

```
f1     f9                 
--------------
1      135.58
2      166.3
4       86.46
5      170.33
```

Update:

The result i want is if f1 = f3 and f3 <> sumoff6 then display the output. As you see below for example it still brings up the result if its the same. Look at the first row, which should not be there because f9 = sumoff6.

query:

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9, allocation_2.[f3], allocation_2.sumoff6
FROM allocation_2 LEFT JOIN statement ON allocation_2.[f3]=statement.f1
WHERE statement.f9 <> allocation_2.sumoff6
GROUP BY statement.f1, statement.f9, allocation_2.[f3], allocation_2.sumoff6
ORDER BY statement.f1;
```

Output:

```
f1            f9     f3        sumoff6
--------------------------------------
123456789   135.58  123456789   135.58
111111111   166.3   111111111   66.3
222222222   86.46   222222222   86.46
333333333   170.33  333333333   170.33
444444444   135.58  444444444   35.58
555555555   125.74  555555555   125.74
666666666   73.49   666666666   23.49
777777777   187.99  777777777   87.99
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your first query is basically correct.  The problem is probably that numbers *look* the same but are really different  Does this fix the problem?

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9
FROM statement INNER JOIN
     allocation_final
     ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1]
WHERE ABS([allocation_final].sumoff6 - statement.f9) < 0.01
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Alot of the times the numbers "in the back ground" arent actually==. This is hyper infuriating sometimes. There's really good posts here on SO related to SQL about how to find where and how theyre different. Sometimes you end up in a hex value rabbit hole other times its float versus decimal etc etc.

Comment: Its weird because i am looking at the f1 numbers are the same and so are the amounts. They should not be coming up

Comment: Use data type Currency whenever you have no more than four decimals and no extremely large values.